# Getting nested data attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

http://api.jquery.com/data/

I'm trying to do something like this with the data method:

```
$("body").data("bar", { myType: "test", count: 40 });
```

However, I can't seem to set "count" like this:

```
$("body").data(bar["count"], 41);
```

Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: You cant do $("body").data(bar["count"], 41); first argument need to be a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is `.data( key, value )`. `data(bar["count"], 41);`is equal to `data(40, 41);`.

If you want to change the value of your object you can do `$("body").data("bar").count = 41`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use it like this:

```
$("body").data({ baz: [ 1, 2, 3 ] });

// then

var data = $("body").data();
console.log(data.baz);  // outputs the array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```